# IntelliJ play scala doesn't recognize file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I faced with a problem that IntelliJ doesn't recognize one particular file in project and treat that file like a some txt file. Below you hove like it looks like in project tree.

[image: aoeu]

Dashboards.scala has some object inside but here it isn't recognized. If I change name into other (non Dashboard) it automatically works. I run `play idea` but that doesn't solve problem.

Do you have any solution for that kind of problem?

Comment: By does not recognize... do you mean file-icon... ? It's just icon... why does it matter if Idea shows correct icon or not.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, why not just use vi or emacs then? One of the factors for choosing IDEs is that the visual representation of the project in IDE conveys information about the project elements at a glance, almost subconciously.

Comment: @bioky, it's best to raise a ticket for this on the intellij issue tracker website; you will get a faster response I think.

Comment: did you re-import the project

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh no I mean that I can't use IDE features with that file.

Comment: @Nami I didn't I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Click "File"==> "Settings"
- Step 2: Expand "Editor" & Click "File Types"
- Step 3: You will see all file types on Right. Navigate to the "Text Files" and Click it
- Step 4: You should able to see your file name on the bottom of Registered Patterns (lower box)
- Step 5: Remove your file from the Registered Patterns. The problem should solved and let you to rename with Dashboards.scala
- Step 6: If not, delete the file from the project and create it again with name Dashboards.scala